# Mutual Information - Correlation, Continuous Random Variables

Tags: it.information-theory

For the Gaussian case $I(X,Y)=f( \varrho )$ where $\varrho $ is the correlation coefficient, and $f$ is a known increasing function. Is there any known joint distribution where the $f$ is not strictly increasing, so for big values of  $\varrho $ the  $I(X,Y)$ might be small. Is there any way to construct such a distribution by applying a transformation on a random variable and by using a known distribution?

Comment: I can come up with a mixture of Gaussians example, but that wouldn't be very elegant...

Comment: I would like to see it. Even a family of pmfs that has this property ( for the discrete case ) might be interesting.

Comment: I mean, it's not difficult to have high MI while CC is 0. Last row of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#/media/File:Correlation_examples2.svg should give you some ideas. Sorry, too busy today to give you a detailed example.